# GC interruptions and TPL

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library

I have a WCF service. During the service's work, it needs to call two web services. So there's code similar to this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _service1.Run(query));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _service2.Run(query));
Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1 , task2 });
```

Most of the time this works OK, but occasionally I was seeing spikes in the execution time, where the first task took a few seconds to even begin. Looking at perfmon, I realized this was exactly when GC was happening. Apparently, GC was a higher priority then running my tasks. This is not acceptable, as latency is very important to me, and I'd prefer GC to happen between requests and not in the middle of a request.

I attempted to go about this a different way, and instead of spinning my own tasks, I used [WebClient.DownloadStringTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705251/can-webclient-download-more-than-one-string-at-the-same-time-c).

```
return webClient.DownloadStringTask(urlWithParmeters).ContinueWith(t => ProcessResponse(clientQuery, t.Result),
                                                                           TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

This didn't help; The GC now runs after the task began, but before the continuation. Again, I guess it figured the system is now idle, so it is a good time to begin GC. Only, I can't afford the latency.

Using TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, which causes the scheduler to use non thread-pool threads, seems to solve this, but I don't want to create so many new threads - this code is going to run a lot (several times per request).

What is the best way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Just how long is the GC interuption?

Comment: Anywhere between 0.5-3 seconds.

Comment: A hacky solution would be to call `GC.Collect` after the call, but if you have many requests, that will be counter-intuitive. Have you tried tuning the GC settings ie `GCLatencyMode.LowLatency` ? Also, is this .NET 2 or 4? If .NET 2, you might need to turn on concurrent GC in the config file. Or turning it off might provide better latency.

Comment: .NET 4.0, using server GC. Haven't tried GCLatencyMode, will check

Comment: Try turning off server GC. Under server GC, there will be 10 times less GC's, but with higher latency.

Comment: Actually server GC gave us a huge performance benefit when multiple users were making requests. Looks like GCLatencyMode isn't available for server GC.

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by the GC? It sounds more like the `ThreadPool` takes some time to schedule your `Task`s, because it's already executing other `Task`s on all of the CPUs. Another possibility is that it's caused by [`DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit).

Comment: The spikes definitely correlate to GC spikes.

Comment: Also, other CPU cores are not busy.

Comment: If it's GC, I'm not sure how LongRunning would fix it. FWIW, WaitAll is wasting a thread.  What's the behavior if you call GC.Collect at the end of the request with the original code?

Comment: Calling GC.Collect at the end doesn't help, as there is a lot of memory consumed during the request, and the GC (I'm guessing) is kicking in to release that memory. I'm also not sure why LongRunning fixes it. Looks like these threads begin their work immediately, and aren't waiting to be scheduled to work, so GC doesn't get the chance to interrupt.

Comment: GC is not triggered by idling. The most common cause is allocation, so my guess is that your tasks are allocating a lot.

Comment: They're not allocating anything actually, other than a WebClient object

Comment: And also, the delay is even before the tasks begin

Comment: @DoronYaacoby Delay before starting the `Task` is another thing that points to `ThreadPool`.

Comment: As said before, this does not look like a GC problem. How did you make sure it is the GC, exactly? How big is your heap? A GC should not take seconds for most heaps.

Comment: I ran perfmon with the "%Time in GC" counter. I then correlated the times of the slowdowns (where my task wouldn't start) with times where this counter was high. They were exactly correlated. Every time the 'task doesn't start' issue happened, there was a spike in the counter.

Comment: If the problem *really* is the GC (which, as others have pointed out, seems unlikely), then the answer is to generate less garbage

Comment: I'm delving into that as well. But I really want the GC to just not interfere at this point. That it would behave exactly like it would have behaved had it been a synchronous operation.

Comment: And I still don't understand why everyone is insisting this is not a GC issue when the data distinctly shows otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Let me first clean up some misunderstandings seen on this page:

- GC does not take place when idle. It takes place when triggered due to a failing allocation (new), GC.Collect or OS memory pressure
- The GC can stop application threads. It does not run concurrently (at least for a certain amount of time)
- "% time in GC" is a counter that does not change between GCs meaning that you might be seeing a stale value
- Async code does not help with GC problems. In fact, it generates *more* garbage (Tasks, IAsyncResult's and probably something else)
- Running your code on dedicated threads does not prevent them being stopped

How to fix this?

1. Generate less garbage. Attach a memory profiler (JetBrains is easy to use) and see what is generating garbage and what is on your heap
2. Reduce heap size to reduce pause time (A 3GB heap is probably due to some caching? Maybe shrink the cache?)
3. Start multiple ASP.NET sites with the same app, hook up GC notifications to sense a GC coming and take some of the IIS sites out of load balancing rotation while they are having a GC (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jclauzel/archive/2009/12/10/gc-notifications-asp-net-server-workloads.aspx?Redirected=true)

You'll notice that there is no easy fix. I don't know one, but if the problem is caused by GC one of the above will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. If what you're saying is true, how do you explain the fact GC doesn't interrupt if I am making synchronous service calls instead of async calls?

Comment: How many concurrent service calls do you have? A lot (like 50)? In your question you said the problem does not happen when using LongRunning task, not matter if synchronous or asynchronous. Correct?

Comment: No, just two calls. And correct, LongRunning solves it (although not scalable, of course).

Comment: About your other questions: Yes, we are caching A LOT of stuff in the process startup. Shrinking this is not really an option, we need things to be fast as possible and cannot load from disk in a middle of a request.
Also, I should mention that we are not running on IIS, this is self hosted WCF.

Comment: How often does this pause happen (in percent of the calls you make)?; As you cannot shrink your heap, I'd try suggestion (1) and profile where the garbage is coming from.

Comment: It happens in about 2% of the calls. I'm trying to profile now, but man, profiling with such a large heap is slow as hell

Comment: (and it still wouldn't explain the difference between ThreadPool/LongRunning/synchronous operations)

Comment: Async code generates more garbage than synchronous code, but *way* less garbage than explicit threads.

Comment: Thread pool threads are reused and don't generate garbage. Also, where do you think async continuations run? On the thread-pool.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is about GC, but I'd like to start with talking about the async implementation first and then see if you're still going to be suffering the same issues.

Going off of your initial implementation's sample code, you're going to be wasting three CPU threads waiting for I/O right now:

- The first thread being wasted is the original WCF I/O thread that is executing the call. It's going to be blocked by the Task.WaitAll while the child Tasks are still outstanding.
- The other two threads that are being wasted are the thread pool threads you're using to execute the calls to Service1 and Service2

All that time while the I/O to Service1 and Service2 is outstanding the three CPU threads you're wasting are not able to be used to execute other work and the GC has to tip toe around them.

Therefore my initial recommendation would be to change your WCF method itself to use the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) pattern that is supported by the WCF runtime. This solves the problem of the first wasted thread by allowing the original WCF I/O thread that calls into your service implementation to be returned to its pool immediately to be able to service other incoming requests. Once you've done that, you next want to make the calls to Service1 and Service2 asynchronous as well from the client perspectice. That would involve one of two things:

1. Generating async versions of their contract interfaces that, again, use the APM BeginXXX/EndXXX that WCF supports in the client model as well.
2. If these are simple REST services you're talking to, you have the following other async choices:

   - `WebClient::DownloadStringAsync` implementation (`WebClient` is not my fav API personally)
   - `HttpWebRequest::BeginGetResponse` + `HttpWebResponse::BeginGetResponseStream` + `HttpWebRequest::BeginRead`
   - Go bleeding edge with the new Web API's `HttpClient`

Putting all that together, there would be no wasted threads while you're waiting for a response from Service1 and Service2 in your service. The code would look something like this assuming you took a WCF client route:

```
// Represents a common contract that you talk to your remote instances through
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRemoteService
{
   [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
   public IAsyncResult BeginRunQuery(string query, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState);
   public string EndRunQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult);

}

// Represents your service's contract to others
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
   public IAsyncResult BeginMyMethod(string someParam, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState);
   public string EndMyMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}

// This would be your service implementation
public MyService : IMyService
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginMyMethod(string someParam, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState)
    {
        // ... get your service instances from somewhere ...
        IRemoteService service1 = ...;
        IRemoteService service2 = ...;

        // ... build up your query ...
        string query = ...;

        Task<string> service1RunQueryTask = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(
            service1.BeginRunQuery,
            service1.EndRunQuery,
            query,
            null);

        // NOTE: obviously if you are really doing exactly this kind of thing I would refactor this code to not be redundant
        Task<string> service2RunQueryTask = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(
            service2.BeginRunQuery,
            service2.EndRunQuery,
            query,
            null);

        // Need to use a TCS here to retain the async state when working with the APM pattern
        // and using a continuation based workflow in TPL as ContinueWith 
        // doesn't allow propagation of async state
        TaskCompletionSource<object> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(asyncState);

        // Now we need to wait for both calls to complete before we process the results
        Task aggregateResultsTask = Task.ContinueWhenAll(
             new [] { service1RunQueryTask, service2RunQueryTask })
             runQueryAntecedents =>
             {
                 // ... handle exceptions, combine results, yadda yadda ...
                 try
                 {
                     string finalResult = ...;

                     // Propagate the result to the TCS
                     taskCompletionSoruce.SetResult(finalResult);
                 }
                 catch(Exception exception)
                 {
                     // Propagate the exception to the TCS 
                     // NOTE: there are many ways to handle exceptions in antecedent tasks that may be better than this, just keeping it simple for sample purposes
                     taskCompletionSource.SetException(exception);
                 }
             });

         // Need to play nice with the APM pattern of WCF and tell it when we're done
         if(asyncCallback != null)
         {
             taskCompletionSource.Task.ContinueWith(t => asyncCallback(t));
         }

         // Return the task continuation source task to WCF runtime as the IAsyncResult it will work with and ultimately pass back to use in our EndMyMethod
         return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public string EndMyMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Cast back to our Task<string> and propagate the result or any exceptions that might have occurred
        return ((Task<string>)asyncResult).Result;
    }
}
```

Once you've got that all in place, you will technically have NO CPU threads executing while the I/O with Service1 and Service2 is outstanding. In doing this, there are no threads for the GC to even have to worry about interrupting most of the time. The only time there will be actual CPU work happening now is the original scheduling of the work and then continuation on the ContinueWhenAll where you handle any exceptions and massage the results.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. My service contract forces me to be synchronous (my clients are not .net clients), so I have to wait for the two service calls to return in order to continue processing the request. You're right that my first code sample wastes three threads, but in the second sample I'm doing something very similar to what you suggested (except my service is synchronous so I have to wait for the tasks from DownloadStringTask to complete), but GC still interrupts.

Comment: @DoronYaacoby Just because the client needs to be synchronous (.NET or otherwise) does not mean your service implementation needs to be. It's a completely server side decision to be asynchronous or not. Changing your service contract to be async will not change the SOAP level signature of the method at all. I hope you will consider again as it will only benefit yourself. In the end, the GC is just another thread that has to compete with your application threads and the less time your application is spent blocking in external calls the more easily the GC will be able to do its job. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Anyway, the change would still be enormous and would require me to change hundreds of interfaces (this is a low level call inside quite a complex system). Not very plausible for this specific service.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend you reconsider Drew's answer. A fully-asynchronous system would be ideal.

But if you want to change less code, you can use `FromAsync` instead of `StartNew` (this requires asynchronous proxies for `Service1` and `Service2`):

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(_service1.BeginRun, _service1.EndRun, query, null);
var task2 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(_service2.BeginRun, _service2.EndRun, query, null);
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

This reduces the number of thread pool threads used per `WaitAll` from 3 to 1. You're still not at the ideal (0), but you should see an improvement.

Comment: Async code will not avoid the GC latency and it will produce even more garbage.

Comment: There will still be GC latency, but I'm not sure it'll produce more garbage. I haven't measured it, but my guess would be it's about the same. But this solution relieves a lot of the pressure on the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this, but it could just kick the problem down the road a bit:

```
try
{
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.LowLatency;

    // Generation 2 garbage collection is now
    // deferred, except in extremely low-memory situations

    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _service1.Run(query));
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _service2.Run(query));
    Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1 , task2 });
}
finally
{
    // ALWAYS set the latency mode back
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = oldMode;
}
```

Credit should be given to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/153498/mgbowen

Comment: LowLatency doesn't work for Server GC, which is what I'm using

Comment: Interesting - Is this by design or just your observation?  Thanks for the feedback, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute many web requests you load quite a lot of temporary objects into the managed heap. While the heap does grow the GC will try to free some memory before allocating a new GC segment. This is the prime reason why you see GCs happening while you are doing work.

Now comes the interesting part: Your GC Heap is already 3 GB and you have some web requests with **short lived** objects additionally on the GC heap. Full GCs will take a lot of time to traverse your certainly complex object graph (all the 3 GB) for dead objects. In such a high throughput scenario where you are getting for each request a substantial amount of temp data over the wire you will be forcing a lot of GCs.

At this point you are GC bound: The application performance is no longer under your control. You can fix this normally by careful design of your data structures and access patterns but the GC times will largely (I guess >95%) dominate your application performance.

There is no easy way out of this. To make the GC segmetns smaller by checking your overall memory consumption may be hard if it is a large complex system. An alternative might be to spawn off an extra process (no not a new AppDomain since the GC is not aware of AppDomains at all) and create your short lived objects there in your web requests. Then you **could** get out of this mess if you can calculate a meaningful response in your small process which is then used by your big server process. If your process does create an equal amount of temp data as your original web requests you are back at square one and you have gained nothing.

It might help to reuse objects from previous web requests and keep a pool of objects ready to reduce the number of allocations.

If you have a lot of identical strings in your process heap it might help to intern them if they are never freed anyway. This could help to simplify your object graph.

Comment: Am I not allocating the same exact amount of memory when using LongRunning tasks? Or when doing synchronous web requests? Why doesn't it happen there? Also, the GC that happens is Gen1 and not full GC.

Comment: To find out why you need to get some call stacks when a GC is happening. You can break into Windbg for CLR notification exceptions which should give you a clue whis operation did trigger a GC.